# Selenium scripts are running locally but failing in jenkins because of TimeOutException

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, webdriver, explicit

I m running the selenium scripts, they are running fine locally but are failing in Jenkins.
I am using Behave and Page Object Model. The behave has 5 steps and the first one is `Which` step and 2-4 steps are `And` steps are the final step is `Given` step. It is inconsistent and is failing at a different step I run the script in Jenkins with the below error.

```
        File "/data/jenkins/workspace/vironment_UI_Integration_Scripts/integration_tests/tests/pages/base_page.py", line 24, in wait_till_element_is_clickable
          element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))
        File "/data/jenkins/workspace/vironment_UI_Integration_Scripts/local_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
          raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

I am using explicit waits and I have tried increasing the timeout period as well. But it is not working.I have tried all the other options using trial and error method but couldn't find any success.

Comment: Have you tried all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645355/6505847)

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 tried with explicit waits, action chains and scroll views. didnt work for me