# Wait for programatic scroll selenium / protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I have an app which includes a button that you click which scrolls the page using JS.

I get a "Element is not clickable at point (somepoint,somepoint)" error, I think this is because selenium/protractor isn't aware of the dynamic scroll and so isn't waiting for it, how can I set a specific time to wait before attempting the next action?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [protractor expected conditions](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) like

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

buttonThatScrolls.click();
var nextElement = $('#xyz'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(nextElement), 10000);
nextElement.click();
```

Comment: I ended up just using browser.wait(), however your solution might be better, is EC.presenceOf equivalent to `browser.wait(function () {
            return (elmLocator).isPresent();
        }, 3000);`? because I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: @Melbourne2991 Like all WebdriverJS  methods `isPresent()` returns a promise and wait expects a function to return true/false. So your method should be like `browser.wait(function () { return (elmLocator).isPresent().then( return function(isPresent) { return isPresent;}); }, 3000);`

Comment: Also `EC.presenceOf` uses `isPresent`. Check protractor code [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/expectedConditions.js#L288-L290)

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to *move to element* before clicking:

```
browser.actions.mouseMove(elm).perform();
```

Or [scroll into it's view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm);
```

---

Note that there is a hacky workaround - click the element *via javascript*:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm);
```

which may work as is, but make sure you know the difference:

- [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click)

---

And, to add to the @nilesh's answer, [`elementToBeClickable` expected condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable) sounds like a better fit in this particular case:

```
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000);
```