# ElementNotVisibleError although visible in test browser

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

Trying to get this to work for one day now.

I want to click on an element that is visible in browser while e2e testing, however I get the error 

`ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible`

The element IS visible in the test browser!

I want to click on the first

`line`

element which is a child of

`<g class="ct-series ct-series-a">`

which is a distant child of

`stackedBar`

## Html

`<chartist id="stackedBar" class="ct-chart ct-golden-section" chartist-data="stackedBar.data" chartist-chart-type="{{stackedBar.type}}"
          chartist-chart-options="stackedBar.options" chartist-events="stackedBar.events">
          </chartist>`

## Test

```
var chart = element(by.id('stackedBar'));
    var series = chart.element(by.css('.ct-series-a'));
    var bars = series.all(by.css('.ct-bar'));
    var bar = series.all(by.css('.ct-bar')).first();

```
chart.isDisplayed().then(function (a) {
      browser.debugger();

  console.log("chart isDisplayed", a)
});

chart.isPresent().then(function (a) {
  browser.debugger(); // element is visible in browser!

  console.log("chart isPresent", a)
});

series.isDisplayed().then(function (a) {
  browser.debugger(); // element is visible in browser!

  console.log("series isDisplayed", a)
});

series.isPresent().then(function (a) {
      browser.debugger();

  console.log("series isPresent", a)
});
```

bars.count().then(function (a) {
      console.log('bars count', a);
    });

bar.isDisplayed().then(function (a) {
          browser.debugger();

```
  console.log("bar isDisplayed", a)
});

bar.isPresent().then(function (a) {
      browser.debugger();

  console.log("bar isPresent", a)
});

bar.getAttribute('class').then( function(a) {
  console.log( "class", a)
});

bar.getAttribute('ct:meta').then( function(a) {
  console.log( "meta", a)
});

bar.click(); //  ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

setTimeout( function() {
      done();
},20000);
```

```

## Html live (npm run protractor-debug)

`<chartist id="stackedBar" class="ct-chart ct-golden-section ng-isolate-scope" chartist-data="stackedBar.data" chartist-chart-type="Bar" chartist-chart-options="stackedBar.options" chartist-events="stackedBar.events">
          <div class="ct-tooltip" style="display: none; left: 634px; top: 287px;"><p>Tag: <b>20. Januar 2016</b></p><p class="spacer-20"><b>Angenommen (G)</b></p><p>Anzahl absolut: <b>5</b></p><p>Anzahl prozentual: <b>100%</b></p></div><svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-bar" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><g class="ct-grids"></g><g><g class="ct-series ct-series-a"><line x1="90.57142857142857" x2="90.57142857142857" y1="450" y2="106" class="ct-bar" value="4" meta="G|2016-01-14|0|0|4"></line><line x1="191.71428571428572" x2="191.71428571428572" y1="450" y2="192" class="ct-bar" value="3" meta="G|2016-01-15|0|0|3"></line><line x1="292.85714285714283" x2="292.85714285714283" y1="450" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="5" meta="G|2016-01-16|0|0|5"></line><line x1="394" x2="394" y1="450" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="5" meta="G|2016-01-17|0|0|5"></line><line x1="495.1428571428571" x2="495.1428571428571" y1="450" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="5" meta="G|2016-01-18|0|0|5"></line><line x1="596.2857142857142" x2="596.2857142857142" y1="450" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="5" meta="G|2016-01-19|0|0|5"></line><line x1="697.4285714285714" x2="697.4285714285714" y1="450" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="5" meta="G|2016-01-20|0|0|5"></line></g><g class="ct-series ct-series-b"><line x1="90.57142857142857" x2="90.57142857142857" y1="106" y2="106" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="Y|2016-01-14|0|0|4"></line><line x1="191.71428571428572" x2="191.71428571428572" y1="192" y2="192" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="Y|2016-01-15|0|0|3"></line><line x1="292.85714285714283" x2="292.85714285714283" y1="20" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="Y|2016-01-16|0|0|5"></line><line x1="394" x2="394" y1="20" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="Y|2016-01-17|0|0|5"></line><line x1="495.1428571428571" x2="495.1428571428571" y1="20" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="Y|2016-01-18|0|0|5"></line><line x1="596.2857142857142" x2="596.2857142857142" y1="20" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="Y|2016-01-19|0|0|5"></line><line x1="697.4285714285714" x2="697.4285714285714" y1="20" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="Y|2016-01-20|0|0|5"></line></g><g class="ct-series ct-series-c"><line x1="90.57142857142857" x2="90.57142857142857" y1="106" y2="106" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="R|2016-01-14|0|0|4"></line><text x="90.57142857142857" y="96" style="" class="ct-bar-label">4</text><line x1="191.71428571428572" x2="191.71428571428572" y1="192" y2="192" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="R|2016-01-15|0|0|3"></line><text x="191.71428571428572" y="182" style="" class="ct-bar-label">3</text><line x1="292.85714285714283" x2="292.85714285714283" y1="20" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="R|2016-01-16|0|0|5"></line><text x="292.85714285714283" y="10" style="" class="ct-bar-label">5</text><line x1="394" x2="394" y1="20" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="R|2016-01-17|0|0|5"></line><text x="394" y="10" style="" class="ct-bar-label">5</text><line x1="495.1428571428571" x2="495.1428571428571" y1="20" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="R|2016-01-18|0|0|5"></line><text x="495.1428571428571" y="10" style="" class="ct-bar-label">5</text><line x1="596.2857142857142" x2="596.2857142857142" y1="20" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="R|2016-01-19|0|0|5"></line><text x="596.2857142857142" y="10" style="" class="ct-bar-label">5</text><line x1="697.4285714285714" x2="697.4285714285714" y1="20" y2="20" class="ct-bar" value="" meta="R|2016-01-20|0|0|5"></line><text x="697.4285714285714" y="10" style="" class="ct-bar-label">5</text></g></g><g class="ct-labels"><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="40" y="455" width="101.14285714285714" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 101px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">14. Januar 2016</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="141.14285714285714" y="455" width="101.14285714285714" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 101px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">15. Januar 2016</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="242.28571428571428" y="455" width="101.14285714285717" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 101px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">16. Januar 2016</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="343.42857142857144" y="455" width="101.14285714285711" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 101px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">17. Januar 2016</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="444.57142857142856" y="455" width="101.14285714285711" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 101px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">18. Januar 2016</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="545.7142857142857" y="455" width="101.14285714285722" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 101px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">19. Januar 2016</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="646.8571428571429" y="455" width="101.14285714285711" height="20"><span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 101px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">20. Januar 2016</span></foreignObject></g></svg></chartist>`

## Console output:

`chart isDisplayed true
chart isPresent true
series isDisplayed true
series isPresent true
bars count 7
bar isDisplayed false
bar isPresent true
class ct-bar
meta null
...
ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a click *with javascript*:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", bar.getWebElement());
```

See [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click) for more information about this solution.

---

Or, you can try *moving to element* before making a click:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(bar).click().perform();
```

Or, [scrolling into element's view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", bar.getWebElement());
bar.click();
```

Comment: `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", bar.getWebElement());` gives `UnknownError: unknown error: arguments[0].click is not a function`

Comment: using protractor `~2.5.1`