# RSelenium cannot access DOM

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am using Selenium on [Stockpair Website](https://www.stockpair.com/sp#trading/page)

```
s = remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "chrome")
s$open()
url <- "https://www.stockpair.com/sp#trading/page"
s$navigate(url)
dir <- s$findElement("css selector", "div.stockSelectionButton.left")
dir$clickElement()
```

I get the error

```
Error:   Summary: StaleElementReference
     Detail: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException
```

I researched that it happens if the DOM changes by an asynchronous process. However, I tested with Selenium running chrome.exe visible and the DOM doesnt change and th element is still there after loading the page.

Can there be other causes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite a dynamic site with periodical updates which change the DOM.

Click the element *via JavaScript*:

```
s$executeScript("arguments[0].click();", list(dir))
```

Also see:

- [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click)

Comment: thanks but with your code I get Error:  Summary: UnknownError
   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
   class: org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonException
In addition: There were 28 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: this works: s$executeScript("$('div.stockSelectionButton.left').click();",  args = list())

Comment: @user670186 ah, forgot to call the list, please retest. Thanks.