# Click checkbox not working using Selenium webdriver even if checkbox is displayed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

Using Selenium webdriver, I am trying to click checkbox but not able to do so, even if the element is displayed.

**Below is my code:**

```java
WebElement element = 
new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 1000).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(object))));
element.isDisplayed(); // returns true
element.getAttribute("type"); // returns checkbox
element.isSelected(); // returns false

element.click();
element.isSelected(); // still returns false
```

The element is displayed, but I am still not able to select the checkbox.
What could be the reason? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: One reason could be, that it is not enabled. Have u tried `element.isEnabled()`

Comment: it's enabled . element.isEnabled() returns true

Answer (score 4):

You may try *moving to the checkbox* and then clicking:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

Or, make the click *via JavaScript*:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

But, make sure you understand the reason you have to do it: [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click)

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for months. For anyone else googling this in the future, if using RSelenium, this works, with a few modifications. You don't need to load a JavascriptExecutor driver. You can call the function and execute the script directly from the RSelenium driver object. The code looks like this: remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].click();", args=list(webElem))

Answer (score 0):

I tried it the same way as you, only in C#. I was able to click the CheckBox and saw it change its state on the screen. But when I tried to read the selected state of the checkbox, I got an exception: `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`.

If I use the page factory to obtain the WebElement, this doesn't happen. So maybe you should try Selenium's PageFactory pattern. It's cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle it , please see below :

1. Using action class for the click :
   [Link to Official documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)

   As the method documentation says,

> Call perform() at the end of the method chain to actually perform the actions.

The general way to achieve click using Actions class is below :

```
actionsObj.moveToElement(element1).click().build().perform()
```

2. If Actions class fails , sometimes the reason can be that you receive below exception :

   ElementNotInteractableException [object HTMLSpanElement] has no size and location

That can mean two things :

a.  Element has not properly rendered: Solution for this is just to use implicit /explicit wait

- **Implicit wait :**

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
- **Explicit wait :**

  WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
  element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("fa-stack-1x")));

b. **Element has rendered but it is not in the visible part of the screen: Solution is just to scroll till the element. Based on the version of Selenium it can be handled in different ways but I will provide a solution that works in all versions :**

```
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element1);
```

1. Suppose all this fails then another way is to again make use of Javascript executor as following :
   executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element1);