# Check a checkbox using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have a simple checkbox which I would like to check, using protractor (AngularJS).

I tried:

```
$('.checkbox-class-name').click();
```

But it does not help. The selector is working (finding my element), but no luck with the click. I also tried:

```
it('should test something if checkbox is checked', function (done) {
   myPage.navigate();
   $('.checkbox-class-name').click().then(function() {
     //expect something here
     done();   
   })
});
```

But it does not work (it is getting inside the 'then' but if I pause the browser I see that the checkbox is not checked)

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** my HTML code:

```
<div ng-if="vm._getTermsAndConditionsFlag()">
   <input class="checkbox-class-name" id="checkbox-name"
          ng-model="vm.termsAndConditionsChecked" type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkbox-name" >I agree to the terms & conditions</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, check if this is the only element matching the selector and you are actually locating the desired checkbox. Also, try *moving to the element* and then making a click:

```
var checkbox = $('.checkbox-class-name');
browser.actions().mouseMove(checkbox).click().perform();
```

Or, *scroll into element's view*:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", checkbox.getWebElement());
checkbox.click();
```

Or, *click via JavaScript* (do understand the [implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click) though):

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkbox.getWebElement());
```

Comment: Thanks. 1. This is the only class (unique), and the selector is working (tested 'isPresent' and got true). 2. Trued moving it - did not work ):

Comment: @YanivEfraim okay, thanks, updated with couple more options.

Comment: This worked for me , thanks for the solution.here is how I have implemented this PageOR.lblShowDisabledReq.isDisplayed().then(data => {
   if (data == true) {
    console.log("Show disable is present");
    browser.actions().mouseMove(PageOR.chckShowDisabledReq).click().perform();
    this.scrollpage.scrollDown();
    console.log("Show disable is clicked");
   }