# ion-option-button in protractor test - click not registered

Tags: ionic-framework, protractor, appium

I've got an ionic app, with an ionic-list with onionic-option-button. This button becomes visible when a user swipes to the left.
I want to write a protractor (Chromedriver & Android & Appium & Protractor tests) test to swipe to the left, and click the button. The swipe is no problem, I can see the button becomes visible, but the click is not registered. The ion-option-button has an ng-click event that does trigger the event.
I've tried:

- Get the ion-option-button element and click it
- Tried using tap instead
- Tried to tap on the location, calculated by grabbing the ion-item (that contains the ion-option-button) and calculating where the ion-button-button is
- Using tapAndHold, wait, and release
- Used browser.driver.touchActions().tap(element)

I don't get any errors that the element is not clickable. The event is just not registered; so it looks like the ion-option-button listens to another event?

It works with Javascript:

```
browser.driver.executeScript('angular.element(document.getElementById("delete-button-0")).triggerHandler("click");');
```

Comment: `browser.driver.touchActions().tap(element)` - did you call `perform()` at the end?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Verified that, I do a perform().

Comment: Just to check on the last statement, if you click via javascript (`executeScript`) - it works and the element is getting clicked - right?

Comment: @alecxe I did not test that yet, but I just did. And yes, that is working:

browser.driver.executeScript('angular.element(document.getElementById("delete-button-0")).triggerHandler("click");');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you make the swipe to the left action, try *waiting for the element to be clickable*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.id("delete-bu‌​tton-0"));

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000);
elm.click();  
// or browser.actions().touchActions().tap(elm).perform();
```

Or, you may need to *move to the element and then click* (or tap):

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).click().perform();
```

You can also try *scrolling into element's view* before making a click/tap:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm.getWebElement());
```

---

And, only as a last resort and if everything else is not working, click it via javascript:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement());
```

There are drawbacks to this solution, make sure you understand the difference:

- [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34562061/771848)

Comment: Thank you!! waiting for it to be clickable solved the issue. Makes sense too.

Comment: why use .perform()

Comment: only the browser method works for my ionic-tab-button . I have no idea why the element is not clickable it seems, any hints?  this works :    await browser.executeScript(`
    const btn = document.getElementById('tab-button-switchRole');
    btn.click();`); This does not :       const wissel_button = element(by.id('tab-button-switchRole')); wissel_button.click() . I would love to know how to fix it, because I want to be sure my test actually tests the user being able to click.