# Click on invisible button on webpage (google maps)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I try to click on plus by xpath. But this plus becomes visible after the mouse cursor on it and my code can't click on this.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[12]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]').click()
```

Is there any way in selenium webdriver to click on invisible elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please do it like below (code sample)

https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("")
hidden_submenu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).click(hidden_submenu).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click [*via javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click):

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Though, I would use ["Action Chains"](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) to perform the mouse over + click.