# Unable to click the linktext using selenium execute_script function using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Unable to click the linktext using **selenium** `execute_script` function

This is what I am tring to do:

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementByLinktext('Level 1s').click;")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *not calling* the `click()` method:

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementByLinktext('Level 1s').click();")
                                                                   FIX HERE^
```

Note that you can also locate the element with selenium and then pass it into the script:

```
link = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Level 1s')
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)
```

You can also perform the click via selenium directly if applicable:

```
link.click()
```

Also related:

- [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click)