# how to wait for an element to be attached to DOM

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I used code:-

```
public Boolean RetryingFindClick(By by)
    {
        Boolean result = false;
        int attempts = 0;
        while (attempts < 4)
        {
            try
            {

                BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(by).Click();
                result = true;
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            attempts++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But i have been told that this is not a best practice and many times it does not work.

**HTML:**

```
<div _ngcontent-c20="" class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
    <ng-select _ngcontent-c20="" id="UploaderName" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
        <!---->
        <div class="open below" tabindex="0">
            <!---->
            <div class="single">
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <div class="placeholder"> Uploader Name </div>
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <div class="toggle"> ▲ </div>
                <!---->
            </div>
            <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
        <select-dropdown>
            <div class="below" style="width: 723px; top: 32px; left: 0px;">
                <!---->
                <div class="filter">
                    <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="options">
                    <ul>
                        <!---->
                        <!---->
                        <li class="message"> No results found </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </select-dropdown>
```

Comment: i dont know why the post got downgraded.I have done a lot of  research from using Thread.sleep to wait.untill. Wait.untill does not seam to have a method to detect the DOM attachment of the element. It is a preety usefull question for newbies.

Comment: Can you share which element is causing stale element reference , in your code?

Comment: String org = 
       StringRandomGen.generateRandomString();
            R_Org.SendKeys(org);
            RetryingFindClick(By.XPath("//* 
           [@id=\"Organization\"]/select- 
         dropdown/div/div/ul/li"));

Answer (score 3):

You can use the explicit wait condition in order to find the element as below.It will be waited until the element is clickable for the given time.If the element is not attached to the DOM/not clickable within the specified time, then it will throw `TimeoutException`. So, you can specify the required time in wait condition.

**NuGet Package :**

```
DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers
```

**Code:**

```
public Boolean RetryingFindClick(By by){

    try
    {
        var  wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserHelper.WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(by))    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return false;//Element is not found until the specified time
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:**

Please add the click action in your test method (removed from RetryingFindClick method)

```
BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(by).Click();
```

Comment: i used this does not work:-    
 
    



 var wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserHelper.WebDriver,new TimeSpan(0,0,40));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"UserType\"]/select-dropdown/div/div[2]/ul/li")));

Comment: Can you add the html?

Comment: <div _ngcontent-c20="" class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
            <ng-select _ngcontent-c20="" id="UploaderName" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
      <!---->
      <div class="open below" tabindex="0">

          <!----><div class="single">
              <!---->
              <!----><div class="placeholder">
                  Uploader Name
              </div>
              <!---->
              <!----><div class="toggle">
                  ▲
              </div>
              <!---->
          </div>

          <!---->

      </div>
      <!----><select-dropdown>

Comment: sorry i dont know how to edit code or write in stackoverfow

Comment: Based on your xpath, some html tags are missing. can you please share the html after select-dropdown tag as well?

Comment: understand what you are asking for but it is a third party code and we are referencing..so i do not have the code

Comment: select-dropdown>
      <div class="below" style="width: 723px; top: 32px; left: 0px;">

          <!----><div class="filter">
              <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="">
          </div>

          <div class="options">
              <ul>
                  <!---->
                  <!----><li class="message">
                      No results found
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </select-dropdown>

Comment: Can you change the xpath as //select-dropdown//ul/li  and then please try

Comment: It looks, here no result is found is displaying in li tag.Whether it will have any clickable element based on certain condition?

Comment: You need to edit your question and add this HTML since it will probably be useful to others trying to answer the question.

Comment: With the wait, I don't think you want to actually attempt a click of the element... just return a boolean value.

Comment: the problem is all together something else.As the website is JS heavy that is why the clicking of elements through webdriver is behaving such a way:-
Further discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click#34796379