# Selenium WebDriver methods vs. JavaScript executor

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm developing an application for automation of an upload process on a website. Right now it is working with Gecko Driver on Firefox but I want to change to HtmlUnitDriver. For this application I just started using Selenium. At the begin I just used methods on WebElements (e.g. click() ...). Then there was a difficult part where it doesn't worked out. After that I found the JavascpriptExecutor class. This class was the solution of my Problem. Now I am thinking about totally change from WebDriver Methods to JavaScriptExecutor. I think it will be faster and less error-prone. Am I right? Are there any disadvantages for me to change to JavascriptExecutor?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click)

Answer (score 1):

For QA testing generally one should not use JavascriptExecutor.

Read more about [Why using JavascriptExecutor in WebDriver can be dangerous](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-using-javascriptexecutor-in.html).

But for getting stuff done and fast It is great!

Read more about [What are the advantages of using a JavaScript executor in Selenium](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-of-using-a-JavaScript-executor-in-Selenium).

Hope this helps you!