# Selenium Chrome webdriver Java: How to select n-th list item?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following element:

```
<ol class="day-tabs">
    <li class="current"><a href="date1.html">a</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="date2.html">b</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="date3.html">c</a></li>
</ol>
```

As you may see, only the first list item has a class definition.
What I need is to go to the n-th item in the list.

So it is not a problem to do:

```
WebElement days_tabs = chromeWebDriver.findElement(By.className("day-tabs"));
```

and then:

```
ArrayList<WebElement> listItems = new ArrayList<>(days_tabs.findElements(By.tagName("li")));
```

but when I tried

```
    JavascriptExecutor ex = (JavascriptExecutor)chromeWebDriver;
    ex.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", listItems.get(n));
```

I didn't see that the n-th item was selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to do the actual click *via selenium API* and not via JavaScript:

```
listItems.get(n).click();
```

There are some substantial differences between the two as outlined here:

- [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click)

Comment: If you are trying to automate a user scenario, you should (generally) prefer the Selenium click vs the JSE click because JSE can click all kinds of things a user can't like invisible elements, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not trying to access all the `<li>` elements, you can use the selector for the nth element directly.

**XPath:**

```java
WebElement nthElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("ol[@class='day-tabs']/li[n]"));
nthElement.click();
```

**CSS SElector:**

```java
WebElement nthElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ol.day-tabs > li:nth-of-type(n)"));
nthElement.click();
```

Comment: Why a `cssSelector` under the heading of `XPath`?

Comment: Your XPath is missing the opening `//`. `ol[day-tabs]` should be `ol.day-tabs` in the CSS selector. Also, neither of these will work because you have "n" as a string instead of passing in a variable `n`.

Comment: I've fixed the code. It was a mistake I made when I tried to format the code and then I mixed it up in the editor.