# Selenium Javascript Executor Click() searches for element on page before actually clicking on the page

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web

I am automating a website with Selenium, however `click()` is not working. It returns an element that can not be scrolled into view.

I used Javascript Executor to invoke `click()`, the code is written to find an element on the page clicked on after click(). However, Selenium attempts to find the element before it clicks on the website.

I checked the website while the script was running, and it attempts to find the element and then clicks on the page it's on. How do I fix this?

(code below)

I have tried waiting for the element to be clickable using WebDriver. However, it times out every time, so I am out of ideas. Any help is appreciated.

```
  Find_Section = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text()="Text"]')
  Driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Find_Section)
  Tester = Driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Test19')
  Tester.click()
```

Edit:

I believe i have figured out what the problem is according to [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click)
click() behaves like a actual user does and execute_script does not and just calls the event so what i believe is happening is the execute_script is clicking on the event but not doing the same as click() so it isn't loading the page correctly.

The reason why i am using execute_script is because the click() method is throwing can not scroll element into view each time.

I may be wrong about the reason why i think it is not working if so correct me

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out since no one here would help me for anyone interested you need to insert a wait statement before the next element for example

```
try:
    time.sleep(2) # Could be WebDriverWait
    Find_Example = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Example')
    time.sleep(2) # Try to make bot less noticeable 
    Find_Example.click()
except InvalidElement: # Defined in the import section
   # Syntax may be wrong i wrote this by hand in this little text window
   print("\033[31m Could Not Find The Desired Element [STATUS] \033[31m")
   exit()
```