# Python Selenium iissue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So im trying to automate the cookie clicker game here https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/
but Im having a problem purchasing the upgrades
Here is some code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

cookies_count = driver.find_element_by_id("cookies")
cookie = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "bigCookie"))
)
items = [driver.find_element_by_id("productPrice" + str(i)) for i in range(1, -1, -1)]
while True:
    cookie.click()
    count = int(cookies_count.text.split(" ")[0])
    for item in items:
        value = int(item.text)
        if value <= count:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, item))).click()
```

After I reach 17/18 cookies it stops with no error and my explict wait times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item is not directly "clickable" because the browser thinks another element is covering it. So you have to use JavaScript to directly click it:

Replace:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, item))).click()
```

With:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
```

Comment: But is there another way doing it directly with python?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click).