# Convert output from Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Set url and path
url = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets?m=0'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Gabri\anaconda3\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

# Select the item that i want
try:
    dif = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.beatmapset-panel__beatmap-dot')
    dif.text
    print(dif)
except:
    print('not found')
```

I'm trying to select this map difficulty 'expert in purple ' --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7PVG.jpg but i can't continue with my code cuz the output is `"<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3cdaf38d0673d0aebe49733d629eae5c", element="60d6241b-80f7-42c8-bf38-9fd2c8574b08")>"` and i expected that would be a string like "expert" or "--bg:var(--diff-expert);" How i can translate or convert ? I did try to select with `'[class*="beatmapset-panel__beatmap-dot"'` and the output is same. Someone can help me?

Comment: `print(dif.text)` perhaps?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel the output is nothing imgur.com/a/h7Sa1JH =((

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: That's i talking about, this is perfectly what i trying to did, thanks bro =DDDD .You can leave it to me now, I'll take it from here haha, but i'm so thankful for you to teach me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hover to an element, then wait for data to appear and get its text:

Here is the snippet for the first game from the list. To get all games you will need another loop.

I am using `ActionChains` to hover on element. Finding locators for this site was not easy even for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get("https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets?m=0")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".beatmapsets__items-row:nth-of-type(1)>.beatmapsets__item:nth-of-type(1)")))
games = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".beatmapsets__items-row:nth-of-type(1) .beatmapsets__item:nth-of-type(1) .beatmapset-panel__info-row--extra")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(games).perform()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".beatmaps-popup__group")))
levels = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".beatmaps-popup__group .beatmaps-popup-item__col.beatmaps-popup-item__col--name.u-ellipsis-overflow")
for level in levels:
    print(level.text)
```

Output:

```
Hinsvar's Hard
Zelqurre's Insane
Amamir's Shining Stars
```

For iteration through a list of levels use this css selector:

```
.beatmapsets__items-row:nth-of-type(1) .beatmapsets__item:nth-of-type(1) .beatmapset-panel__info-row--extra
```

And iterate this locator:

.beatmapsets__items-row:nth-of-type(**1**) .beatmapsets__item:nth-of-type(1) .beatmapset-panel__info-row--extra,

.beatmapsets__items-row:nth-of-type(**2**) .beatmapsets__item:nth-of-type(1) .beatmapset-panel__info-row--extra

**Update**:
To get scores use:

```
scores= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".beatmaps-popup__group .beatmaps-popup-item__col.beatmaps-popup-item__col--difficulty")
for score in scores:
    print(score.text)
```

The output will be:

```
2.58
3.46
4.55
4.90
5.97
```

Also, check this answer on how to put results in one list: [Trouble retrieving elements and looping pages using next page button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360009/trouble-retrieving-elements-and-looping-pages-using-next-page-button)

And finally read here about css selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

I usually prefer using them because they are shorter.

Comment: I'm so thankful bro, it worked! I also did a loop to show one by one maps, but i have only one more problem =( i can't show the number's beside, cuz only description that your code print is insufficient to filter all maps correctly , i need show these numbers --> https://imgur.com/a/FOJs74a you can help me one more time plz ? =,)

Comment: By the way, you have no idea how much your answer helped me, i learnd sooo much with your code ^-^

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code as following to print the element text:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Set url and path
url = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets?m=0'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Gabri\anaconda3\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

# Select the item that i want
try:
    dif = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.beatmapset-panel__beatmap-dot')    
    print(dif.text)
except:
    print('not found')
```

Comment: Sure, you have to add some wait or delay to make the page load and only after that apply `dif = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.beatmapset-panel__beatmap-dot')` otherwise the element is still not exists or just appeared but still not fully rendered!

Comment: @JD2775 You are right! maybe he is looking for some other element? I see 67 elements located by `div.beatmapset-panel__beatmap-dot` there

Comment: Almost worked, but i still have an unreadable output https://imgur.com/a/h2m8w7F ,any other idea? haha

Comment: @Prophet sorry, I deleted my reply not realizing you would respond :)  I added a new answer

Comment: @JD2775 It's OK. I'm just not sure about what he actually trying to get. In case he is looking for a title as you suggest.. Well, maybe it's you the prophet, not me :)

Comment: @Prophet I just re-read the OP. He is looking for the purple bar. It looks like a hover action and then switch to it and get the text somehow.  Its more complex then I thought intially.  Deleted my answer

Comment: @JD2775 i saw your answer and it help me cuz your resolution is same thing that i will do later, i will make a code to search all maps with difficulty 'expert',filter and put in a list for me. I'm so thankful to you for this <33

Comment: This does not answer the question. The answer is much more complicated.

Comment: @vitaliis maybe you are right, I do not argue. I answered according to what I could understand from the question and the web page