# Protractor does not detect element after login

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

On login page everything works perfect, I can select the inputs, select the submit button and click the submit button, the url changes like I expect, but after the login I can't select elements anymore from some reason.

```
   // #1 login test
  it('should send check in desktop', async () => {

    await loginPage.login(environment.e2e.user.phone, environment.e2e.user.password);

    await loginPage.verifySuccessfullLogin();
    console.log('After verifySuccessfullLogin');

    await browser.sleep(3000);
    console.log('After sleep');

    const sendBtn = $('#sendCheckBtnDesktop');
    console.log(sendBtn);
    await sendBtn.click();

    // Not getting here
    await browser.sleep(10000);
  });
```

Rest of the Code:

```
  navigateToLoginPage() {
    return browser.get(environment.e2e.baseUrl);
  }
  getPhoneInput() {
    return $('#phoneNumber');
  }
  getPasswordInput() {
    return $('#login-password');
  }
  getSubmitButton() {
    return $('#submitLoginBtn');
  }
  verifySuccessfullLogin() {
    return browser.wait(browser.ExpectedConditions.urlContains('/user/personal'), 10000);
  }

  public async login(phone: string = environment.e2e.user.phone, password: string = environment.e2e.user.password) {
    await this.navigateToLoginPage();

    const phoneInput = this.getPhoneInput();
    await phoneInput.sendKeys(phone);

    const passInput = this.getPasswordInput();
    await passInput.sendKeys(password);

    const submitBtn = this.getSubmitButton();
    await submitBtn.click();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: so you fixed the issue, and made the same problem in another place, just as I predicted. I'm still around if you need my help, just ask

Comment: Hi @SergeyPleshakov, how are you, it's the same issue, but I found it's very common to not be able to detect element after login
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/143
If you know how to solve this I will appreciate it.

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I read some of your answers and decided to go with `await` instead of `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's hidden by another element.

You can try:

```
await browser.executeScript(`
    const btn = document.getElementById('sendCheckBtnDesktop');
    btn.click();
`);
```

If it works, this element is not clickable using the protractor (Maybe it's behind another element).

You can read more about the [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34796379) between clicking using protractor to JS.

Answer (score 2):

Problem in this line!

```
return browser.wait(browser.ExpectedConditions.urlContains('/user/personal'), 10000);
```

it should have been

```
return browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.urlContains('/user/personal'), 10000);
```

```
  it('should send check in desktop', async () => {

    // *************
    // HERE!
    // *************
    await loginPage.login(environment.e2e.user.phone, environment.e2e.user.password);

    await loginPage.verifySuccessfullLogin();
    console.log('After verifySuccessfullLogin');

    await browser.sleep(3000);
    console.log('After sleep');

    const sendBtn = $('#sendCheckBtnDesktop');
    console.log(sendBtn);
    // Nothing happens
    await sendBtn.click(); <--------- you were missing await here, but you fixed it

    // Not getting here
    await browser.sleep(10000);
  });
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, thank you for the answer, I understand what `await` is, you can see in my code I used it a few times.
One thing I don't understand is about the login function which works fine without adding `await`, I am not sure why it works, I will add the code to my question.

Comment: @OffirPe'er one command is being executed before the one before is completed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: I added the `await` like you suggested and I Added the rest of my code to the question, still doesn't work....

Comment: while I'm checking take a look and my addition to the answer

Comment: okay, I found one issue and one area for improvement, updated the answer^ @OffirPe'er

Comment: After changing everything just like you mentioned, I still facing the same problem... the click is not working

Comment: I can't select the button element even though it's there, that's so weird, I tried to refresh the page, added sleep methods, navigate, I even put the same submit button from login page and tried to select it without success, the problem is with `Angular`, maybe something in my configurations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232587/discussion-between-sergey-pleshakov-and-offir-peer).