# How to hide the "mat-select" Dropdown

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello Greetings for the day
I am trying to Hide the dropdown after choosing the desired value from the dropdown
The catch here is that designers have used the "mat-select"(Under div tag) rather than the "select" tag.
Solutions that I tried.
1 Clicking on the scroll button at the side of the dropdown
2 Just clicking on a blank screen(Not feasible as it might unselect the value)
https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selectionel
Note when the "mat-select" dropdown is open it hides the focus from other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Why to simply selecting the dropdown options by their id?
There are 3 options in the upper dropdown: Steak, Pizza, Tacos.
Their locators are accordingly:

```
mat-option[id=mat-option-0]
mat-option[id=mat-option-1]
mat-option[id=mat-option-2]
```

Slicking on the option selects it and the dropdown get closed.

Comment: Yes "mat- select" items should automatically get closed after choosing the value but in my case, The dropdown contains multiple checkboxes. like we can choose Pizza and Tacos at same time. So in that case it is not automatically closing.

Comment: I can't share that with anyone as that is still under development. however, I found the way thanks for your help.

Comment: If that helped can you accept the answer?

Comment: OK, but you understand, I could not guess that from the link you provided...

Comment: yes i have updated the link from "https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview" to its sub category "https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selectionel"

Comment: I see. Actually, to close that dwrodown you can simply click on some element out of the dropdown :) I will update the answer shrotly

Comment: I tried it. It will not work as "mat-selects" will not allow to focus on any other element until the dropdown is open. So You will not able to click on the White area.

Comment: You can. In this case you can use JavaScript click

Comment: OK, I just want to understand. Did you try JavaScript click? For example try JavaScript clicking on element located by this CSS locator: `[class='docs-navbar-header']`

Comment: Yes, I did but I clicked on a specific pixel (By scrolling and clicking on that pixel), and that didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure we understand each other. I suggested clicking `[class='docs-navbar-header']` element with JS, not scrolling to any pixel and lick on it

Comment: yes, I already did but clicking on "[class='docs-navbar-header']" didn't work as it hides all the background elements including the top toolbar.

Comment: I wrote you to click it with JavaScript, not with driver.  
element = driver.find_element_by_css-selector("[class='docs-navbar-header']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click

Comment: yes, I already did it with javascript executer but it didnt work on the JDK-14.0.2 and selenium 3 (3.141.59). Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works correctly for me. I use Java 11, but I don't think it should be the Java version issue.  Strange...

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; WebElement toolbar =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='flex-spacer']")); js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", toolbar);

I don't know why it is not working for me. 
Appreciate your help :)

Comment: What are you trying to tell me now? Is that worked?

Comment: No, it didn't work on my machine. just appreciating your effort and time.