# Q: Can't keep clicking button by chorme web driver in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, driver

**Question:**

How can I show all reviews by clicking "Show more reviews" button?

**What did I do:**

1. To scrape all reviews, I decided to Keep clicking until that button disappears.
2. But some new reviews didn't appear after clicking for 8 times (using while below).
3. I already checked xpath of the button but it didn't changed.
4. If I click the button manually without the driver, I can see new reviews.

[image: stack from this review (can see after clicking the button for 8 times)]

```py
import time, random
from selenium import webdriver
from latest_user_agents import get_random_user_agent

### ser user_agent
user_agent = get_random_user_agent()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-agent=" + user_agent)
driverpath = "C:/Users/~~/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=driverpath)

### target url
url = "https://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/truly-wireless/wf-l900/reviews-ratings"

### open URL
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

# accept cookies
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()

# show all reviews
try:
    while True:
        driver.execute_script('window.scroll(0,1000000);') 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reviews_listing_278405943492055451029662"]/div[3]/div[4]/button').click()
        time.sleep(random.randrange(2, 5, 1))
except:
    print("---------------- finish showing all reviews ----------------")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the end of the webpage and then do it as the button might not been loaded fully.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

You might also try to press the button only when it is available.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myElement")))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried both but they didn't work. I can't see the new reviews yet

Answer (score 0):

You can try javascript click:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reviews_listing_278405943492055451029662"]/div[3]/div[4]/button')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

In this method, the scrolling shouldn't be necessary. See more info about the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click).